# Are "knees" and "needs" homophones?

Tags: pronunciation, phonology, phonetics

I saw an English textbook has a /dz/ phoneme, wondering whether it is simply pronounced as [z] with a silenced [d]

Are needs and knees simply homophones?

Comment: Do you pronounce the words the same way?

Comment: I don't know. I'm not a native speaker. That's why I asked the question

Comment: No, they're not. Please don't believe that textbook.

Comment: No, _dz_ is not pronounced _z_.

Comment: /dz/ is pronounced /dz/. That's what it means. Although that isn't normally considered a phoneme in English. It's two phonemes. I assume you have looked at pronunciation in a dictionary. Maybe you could quote the textbook and explain your reasoning.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the only source listed shows they do not rhyme.

Comment: @YosefBaskin It asks about homophones, not rhyming.

Comment: All homophones rhyme, so (a fortiori) if two words do not rhyme they are not homophones.

Comment: English doesn't have /dz/ as one phoneme. /tʃ/ and /dʒ/ are the only affricate phonemes in English. That doesn't mean, however, that the sequence of /d/ + /z/ isn't pronounced like [d͡z] in other languages where it's one phoneme. It just means the sequence is not distributed within English words like other single consonants, whereas /tʃ/ and /dʒ/ are.

Answer (score 1):

z and dz do not sound the same, meaning 'knees' and 'needs' are not homophones, although they sound very similar. The only difference is that when pronouncing them, 'knees' is pronounced n-ee-z when 'needs' is pronounced n-ee-**d**z (bold letters are just there to emphasize).

Sounds:
'n' is the n in ba**n**.
'ee' is the ee in b**ee**.
'z' is the z in fro**z**en.
'dz' is the ds in be**ds**.